# Is it possible to run gRPC with Glassfish application server?

Tags: java, glassfish, grpc-java

I have an Java EE application running on a GlassFish server with a few REST endpoints exposed. This is a monolithic application and It needs to communicate over both Rest and gRPC.

As gRPC can be deployed as a standalone service , it manages it’s own connections and port.

Is it possible to run gRPC on GlassFish server? If not so do I need to split this monolithic application?

**EDIT:**
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 (build 13)

GRPC - Stub 1.28.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an outstanding PR https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/4738 for enabling gRPC servers in a servlet container. You could use the idea there to do your own integration.

If you are not even looking at using the servlet interface, you should be able to use gRPC server inside Glassfish as I am not aware of any conflicts.

Comment: I am not looking at using the servlet interface. When I try to create ManagedChannel I am getting NoClassDefFoundError for  "io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder" at "io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider:31". Problem is these classes are in the same jar package and When I check this package I can see all these classes. I thought there is a conflict between Netty and GlassFish Server.

Comment: Can you post the relevant log messages? The `NoClassDefFoundError` might be for a different class (and not `io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder`

Comment: I have updated my question with log messages. Also there are some answers to related questions confused my mind like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/jJ1HQtN4WuY

Comment: You probably have some error log messages earlier in the file. You should search there for the source of the error. Possibilities are not being able to find netty classes or the native code since those were not loaded.